# media query resize span font-size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working in a wordpress.
I have specific span tag with a size

```
<span id="some_id" style="font-size: 26px;">Some title</span>
```

When the screen, viewport gets small, I want it to reduce the font size, like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #some_id{font-size:15px;}
}
```

but it doesnt work! all other rules inside of this media screen work, except this one

why? thanks!

Comment: Is the current style actually inline or is that just a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styling overrides your css. The order of appearing the css determines wich is most important. If you need to avoid this problem, you need to think in two solutions (select what is better for you)

## Solution 1

```
  <span id="some_id" class="font26">Some title</span>

   .font26 { font-size: 26px; }
```

## Solution 2

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #some_id{font-size:15px !important;}
  }
```

The `!important` operator is dangerous if you don't know how it works. First of all, learning how css is rendering and his priorities.

Good luck

Comment: If this solves your problem, accept this answer as the correct answer (clicking the tick in the bottom of the votes) Thank you :D

Comment: :) :) ;) dont worry. That was my first thought, but I have to wait 10 mins. it says

Comment: Yes, it's only for remember you ;) thank you and see you later!